# Is there any issue with Calendar class in android?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, timezone

I want to print every hour from 30 days back from current date in `CDT` timezone. I have changed the emulator and calendar instance timezone to `CDT`.

But the problem is at the 598th iteration of loop the date gets change automatically. Not sure why this is happening

I have also tried using 
    `final Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();`
but problem is the same

```
package com.example.testapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentTime.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    final Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    startTime.setTime(currentTime.getTime());
    startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    startTime.add(Calendar.DATE, -30);
    printDatesByHours(startTime.getTime());
}

public static Date addTimeToDate(final Date dateTime, int seconds) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(dateTime.getTime() + (seconds * 1000));
    return calendar.getTime();
}

private void printDatesByHours(Date startDate) {
    int i = 30 * 24; //days * hours per day
    int startTime = 0;
    while (i >= 0) {
        Date eventStartDate = addTimeToDate(startDate, startTime);
        Log.d("Date ", eventStartDate.toString());
        startTime = startTime + 3600;
        i--;
    }
}
}
```

By running this code you can see that date suddenly changes on 598th iteration like below printed log.

```
Date: Sun Aug 04 07:00:00 CDT 2019
Date: Sun Aug 04 08:00:00 CDT 2019
Date: Sat Jun 15 15:57:13 CDT 2019
Date: Sat Jun 15 16:57:13 CDT 2019
```

The third and fourth entry in above logs should like below

```
Date: Sun Aug 04 07:00:00 CDT 2019
Date: Sun Aug 04 08:00:00 CDT 2019
Date: Sun Aug 04 09:00:00 CDT 2019
Date: Sun Aug 04 10:00:00 CDT 2019
```

After running the code you will get data from the current time but 598th entry will be wrong. Please help

Comment: I reproduced this bug in Java without using any android libraries, so it at least seems its not related to Android.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). On earlier Android through [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Comment: @OleV.V., due to Java 8 compatibility on Android, `ZonedDateTime` classes weren't transferred over until API 26.

Comment: That’s true, @user2836202, at least partly. There’s a backport that works with lower API levels, that’s the one I was linking to: the ThreeTenABP (ABP for Android Backport).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overflowing your Integer.

`MAX_INT = 2^31 - 1  = 2,147,483,647`
Your problem is that: `598 * 3600 * 1000 = 2,152,800,000` which causes your Integer to become negative and subtract time. If you change start time to a `long` this should resolve your issue.

Comment: Wow, This worked... Nice catch,, Thanks for the help